# Mittag-Leffler function and Laplace Integral

Tags: pr.probability, cv.complex-variables

Let $E_{\alpha}(z)\triangleq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{\Gamma(\alpha n + 1)}$ be the Mittag-Leffler function.

I am looking for a full proof of the following fact (a reference to a proof in the literature is enough for this question):

$\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-u} E_{\alpha}(u^{\alpha}z)du = \frac{1}{1-z}, \alpha > 0$ where the region of convergence of the integral contains the unit circle and is bounded by the line $\text{Re}[z^{1/\alpha}]=1$.

I see the relation inside the unit circle, the interesting part should be outside the unit circle...

Comment: You're asking for a proof that the integral is convergent? (Once you have this, the formula immediately carries over by analytic continuation.)

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes, a proof of convergence outside the unit circle should be enough.